# Where is application class for a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to integrate my android application with Parse SDK. for that I need to include my parse account credentials in application class onCreate() method.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just create another class and extend `Application`:

```
public class App extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Parse SDK stuff goes here
    }
}
```

Then add extended class name to `<application>` tag in the manifest file :

```
android:name=".App"
```

Comment: Thanks ! but I wont be using parse anymore as it is shutting down its services

Comment: Anyway that's the way we do it my friend

Comment: Clear and concise, great answer!